# Unhandled error { Error: You did not provide an API key

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am integrating Stripe into Firebase with my iOS project and this is the error I receive when I try to open PaymentOptionsViewController (in my iOS app simulator):

Unhandled error { Error: You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.

Here is my code in my nodejs index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_test_key);

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
const data = snap.data();
const email = data.email;

const customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email: email })
return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).update({ stripeId : customer.id})
});

exports.createCharge = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

const customerId = data.customerId;
const totalAmount = data.total;
const idempotency = data.idempotency;
const uid = context.auth.uid

if (uid === null) {
    console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated user');
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Illegal access attempt.')
}

return stripe.charges.create({
    amount: totalAmount,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customerId
}, {
    idempotency_key: idempotency
}).then( _ => {
    return
}).catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create charge')
});
})

exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

const customerId = data.customer_id;
const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
const uid = context.auth.uid;

if (uid === null) {
    console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated user');
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Illegal access attempt.')
}

let key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
  {customer: '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}'},
  {stripe_version: '{{2019-05-16}}'}
);


return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: customerId},
    {stripe_version: stripeVersion}
).then((key) => {
    return key
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create ephemeral key.')
})
})



// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//     console.log('This is the console message.')
//  response.send("Hello from JonnyB Codes!");
// });s
```

How do I solve the error above? Let me know if more information is needed to get an answer.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Got this error message in iOS too.
In my case I was not setting correctly the publishable key when the app was launched, before doing the payment. In Swift this did the trick.

```
Stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey("pk_test_....")
```

Probably doesn't solve your issue, but maybe give you a clue.